# java split method to arrays

Tags: java, arrays, split

I have a data like below:

```
3.3 John
3.9 Jim
3.5 Kathy
3.2 Steve
2.4 Stacy
2.8 Faith
```

Code:

```
File StudentGrade = new File("data.txt");
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(StudentGrade);
    int size = reader.nextInt();
    //debug: System.out.println(size);

    String[] gradeArr = new String[size];// array created for grades
    //debug: System.out.println(gradeArr);
    String[] nameArr = new String[size];//array created for name
    String[] temp = new String[100];// array created for temporary array
    int index = 0;//index indicator

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = reader.nextLine();
        //System.out.println(s);
        temp = s.split("\\s+");
        gradeArr[index] = temp[0];
        nameArr[index] = temp[1];
        System.out.println("grades= "+ gradeArr[index]+ " name = "+ nameArr);
        index++;
    }
```

It has to be split to 2 arrays, one is for the numbers, another is for names.
I can get the numbers to `temp[]`, but I don't know how to convert names to another array. Please teach me.

Comment: Please show us how you get the numbers into the array.

Comment: Is your input 2d array of a 1d array?

Comment: it's from a data.txt. Using File to scan it from a text file.

Comment: 1d array for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `split("\\s+")`, the result array would look like this:

```
gradeArr[0] = 3.3;
gradeArr[1] = John;
```

So if you call `gradeArr[1]`, you will get the name.

You need to call `reader.nextLine();` after your `reader.nextInt();`. You need to read the enter character after the `int` so you would be on the next line of the .text file.

The following  code works:

```
File StudentGrade = new File("E:/workspace/Test/src/main/java/data.txt");
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(StudentGrade);
        int size = reader.nextInt();
        // debug: System.out.println(size);
        reader.nextLine();
    String[] gradeArr = new String[size];// array created for grades
    // debug: System.out.println(gradeArr);
    String[] nameArr = new String[size];// array created for name
    String[] temp = new String[100];// array created for temporary array
    int index = 0;// index indicator

    while (reader.hasNextLine()) {
        String s = reader.nextLine();
        // System.out.println(s);
        temp = s.split("\\s+");
        gradeArr[index] = temp[0];
        nameArr[index] = temp[1];
        System.out.println("grades= " + gradeArr[index] + " name = " + nameArr[index]);
        index++;
    }
```

And here is the resutl:

```
grades= 3.3 name = John
grades= 3.9 name = Jim
grades= 3.5 name = Kathy
grades= 3.2 name = Steve
grades= 2.4 name = Stacy
grades= 2.8 name = Faith
```

data.text:

```
6
3.3 John
3.9 Jim
3.5 Kathy
3.2 Steve
2.4 Stacy
2.8 Faith
```

Comment: Thanks. I did check it by print out gradeArr[1], but it shew "null".

Comment: Try `split(" +")`

Comment: Sorry, it actually shows the following: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at testing2.main(testing2.java:24)

Comment: Please edit your question with this new information so new people can participate, and it would be easier for me too.

Comment: Also, please use `split("\\s+")`

Comment: I also doubt that this `IndexOutOfBoundException` is because `size` is 0, so your `nameArr` size is 0.

Comment: Hi, Yassadi, I tried to follow your suggestion, but the outcome shows as following : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
 at testing2.main(testing2.java:25)

Comment: @MarkYo also, please make sure the size of your `nameArr` is not 0.

Comment: Sorry. my first time using this site. I'm still trying to figure out how to edit it. By the way, the nameArr is initiated. The error line is gradeArr[1] = John;... if I tried to assign it to nameArr

Comment: @MarkYo What is the value of `size`? Is it more than 1?

Comment: I just update my code. hope this will make clear. sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @MarkYo I edited my answer, it will solve your problem. I tested it with your code.

Comment: Thanks. it works, and I finally understand why it wouldn't work. I misunderstood your suggestion. I moved "String s = reader.nextLine();" to reader.nextInt();

Answer (score 4):

This looks like a good place to apply a *regular expression*, group the digit.digit white space and consequetive word characters. Iterate matches. Build two `List`(s). Like,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d+\\.\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)");
List<Double> grades = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
String s = "3.3 John 3.9 Jim 3.5 Kathy 3.2 Steve 2.4 Stacy 2.8 Faith";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    grades.add(Double.valueOf(m.group(1)));
    names.add(m.group(2));
}
System.out.printf("%s %s%n", grades, names);
```

Outputs

```
[3.3, 3.9, 3.5, 3.2, 2.4, 2.8] [John, Jim, Kathy, Steve, Stacy, Faith]
```

Comment: Just to add, Array's may not be what you want, you may want to actually make a class representing the record of name to grade, or store in a Map<string, grade>

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Or a tuple, but a POJO with two fields makes a lot of sense (just answering the question OP asked).

Comment: Thanks both of your help. both of your suggestions help.

Comment: Can you use split method to do it?

Comment: Yes, you just need to construct it with the result of spilt yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class HelloTest {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
  try {
   //data.txt contains 6 line data as in your question 
   File file = new File("data.txt");
   Scanner reader = new Scanner(file);
   int size = 6; // six line data so it is 6 
   String[] nameArr = new String[size]; //array created for name
   String[] gradeArr = new String[size]; // array created for temporary array
   int i = 0;
   while (size--> 0) {
    String s = reader.nextLine();
    String[] data = s.split(" ");
    nameArr[i] = data[1];
    gradeArr[i] = data[0];
    i++;
   }

   for (String name: nameArr) System.out.println("name is " + name);
   for (String grade: gradeArr) System.out.println("grade is " + grade);



  } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
   fe.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: HI, Vishnu, Thanks for the suggestion. I tried your suggestion. however, the outcome shows an exception.