# Creating Multiple Arrays From a Text File in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays

I'm in a low level program design class and am struggling with creating arrays from data given in a text file.  The file name is students.txt and it is formatted in this manner:

1234

Joseph

3

4.0 (except it is single spaced)

Where the first number (an integer) is the Student ID, followed by the student name, followed by credit hours, and finished with GPA.  This is an example of course and the file contains many records.

In the end I am going to create a record that is organized in sequential order by one of the fields above.  What I need help with is creating multiple arrays for each field. I'm thinking it would be very helpful if I could have a student_ID array, name array, credit_hour array, and gpa array.

Here is my best shot and attempt:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project     Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package filetoarray;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

/**
 *
 * @author whitn
 */
public class FileToArray {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException {


   //Here I am establishing my arrays
   int[]student_ID;
   student_ID = new int[100];
   String[]name;
   name = new String[100];
   int[]credit_hour;
   credit_hour = new int[100];
   double[]gpa;
   gpa = new double[100];

   // I am not too sure what FileReader and BufferedReader do but I think 
   // I am creating a way for the program to read from the file students.txt
   FileReader fr = new FileReader ("C:\\Users\\whitn\\Desktop\\students.txt");
   BufferedReader snames = new BufferedReader(fr);


   //Here I am initializng my variables
   String name1 = " "; //called name1 to not confuse it with array 'name'
   String next = " ";
   int s_ID = 0;
   int c_hour = 0;
   double gpa1 = 0.0;

   //Now I don't really know how to proceed. Do use something like 
   // student_ID[x] = Integer.parseInt(next)
   // name[x] = snames.nextLn();
   // credit_hour[x] = snames.nextInt();
   // gpa[x] = snames.nextDouble();

   //Do I even need the variable initialized above?



}

}
```

I'm pretty sure if I can figure out how to create an array from the fields provided in the file I can finish the problem.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am in my first programming class and don't know much, therefore, if I've left out valuable information let me know!

Thank you

Comment: You said "except it is single spaced" do you mean that each record is on a single line and each piece of data is separated from the next by a single space? Also how much do you know about manipulating strings?

Comment: Great question! What I mean is there are no blank lines in between each record

Comment: I answered a question like this yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50094030/java-split-method-to-arrays/50094112#50094112

Comment: Because my simple brain thought that is the best route and I'm not sure what a student class is exactly! Edit: This is in response to a deleted question asking why I want to use arrays rather than a student class.

Comment: A class named `Student` that would encapsulate all of the data for a single student. So for example the class would contain member variables for id, name, hours, and gpa. You would then create instances of this class and populate them with the data so that you can have a single collection of `Student` objects rather than multiple collections of individual pieces of data.

Comment: Start by focusing on reading the file one line at a time. Have you done that yet? [How to read line by line by using FileReader](//stackoverflow.com/q/33892453)

Answer (score 0):

You can use readline method of bufferreader to read line by line and that's how you pick one record in the form of string.
Now if are separated by space or comma , you can use string method split which will return you an array of string now by index you can assign values to all your variable by that array of string or you can directly use that array of string

Answer (score 0):

Make a class for reading file content like

```
import java.io.*;

public class FileReader {

    private String fileName, fileContent = null, line;

    public FileReader(String f) {
        fileName = f;
        reader();
    }

    private void reader() {
        try {
            fileContent = "";
            // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding
            Reader fileReader = new java.io.FileReader(fileName);

            // Wrapping FileReader in BufferedReader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                fileContent += line;
                fileContent += '\n';
            }

            // Closing the file
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get content of file
     * 
     * @return String
     */
    public String getFileContent() {
        return fileContent;
    }

}
```

Create a class for Student

```
public class Student {
    public String name;
    public int id, creditHour;
    public double gpa;

    // add constructor and setter/getter methods
}
```

Create a class for starting project with `main` method. get file content from `FileReader` class. Define an array of students. Loop over its content and fill your array.